# Ms acccess SQL Query to get Birthday between two dates

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Ms access SQL Query to get Birthday between two dates

I want to know whose birthday comes between given date. For example FromDate :-27-11-2021 ToDate:- 02-12-2021 I want to get all birthdays between FromDate and ToDate

What I tried:-

```
 SELECT * FROM tblMembers WHERE (Month(DOB) = 11 AND Day(DOB) >= 27) AND (Month(DOB) = 12 AND Day(DOB) <= 02 and Year(DOB)>1753)  OR (Month(DOB) > 11 AND Month(DOB) < 12 and Year(DOB)>1753) and status='Active' Order by Month(dob), Day(dob)
```

When From month and To month is same above query is correct but the different month it's not showing any data.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `between` operator

```
  SELECT *
  FROM tblMembers 
  WHERE dob BETWEEN fromDate AND toDate AND status = 'Active'
  ORDER BY dob
```

Comment: No i dont want to get records between From and To dates , I want to get records of people celebrating birthday between From and To dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblMembers  
WHERE ((DOB) >'27-11-2021' AND (DOB)<'02-12-2021') AND status='Active' 
ORDER BY Month(dob), Day(dob)
```